# Fill gaps within an array with previous values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `salary_raise` which looks like:

```
id | employee_id | salary | year | month | date
1  | 1           | 1000   | 2014 | 2     | 2014-01-30
2  | 1           | 1200   | 2015 | 3     | 2015-02-20
3  | 1           | 1300   | 2015 | 4     | 2015-03-29
```

... and so on for multiple employees. It keeps records only when a raise of salary occurs (and this can occur random over a period of time).

Right now I can extract an array which looks like `$salary['year']['month'] = $salary_value`:

```
[2014]
      [2] => 1000
[2015]
      [3] => 1200
      [4] => 1300
```

I need to extract a full report with the salary in each month up to date (filling automatically the months/years missing), like:

```
[2014]
      [2] => 1000
      [3] => 1000
      [4] => 1000
      [5] => 1000
      [6] => 1000
      [7] => 1000
      [8] => 1000
      [9] => 1000
      [10] => 1000
      [11] => 1000
      [12] => 1000
[2015]
      [1] => 1000
      [2] => 1000
      [3] => 1200
      [4] => 1300
      [5] => 1300
```

I can't figure it out how to do it by using php and/or mysql.
Many thanks!

Comment: hint: create another table that has all of the years you could feasibly require, and another table that has all of the months. then join!

Comment: Is month always 1 month later than the date? If so, there's no need to store month

Comment: No, it's the current month ( date("m") ).

Comment: Plainly, that's not true. But if it is, then there's no point storing it is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to 'fill the gaps' you need to source the information somewhere.

Easiest way to do this in mysql is to have some generic calendar tables, which list single values for things like month numbers, years etc.

So given a table `months(month)`, and a table `years(year)`, the former contains `1..12` and the latter contanis `2010..2017` (for example), we can `cross join` the two of those to give us every month for every year, and then `left join` the `salary_raise` table to this.

That will leave us a table with a few entries and a lot of nulls, so then we need to use some variables to populate the `null` values with the last salary entry.

```
select `year`, `month`, if(salary is null, @prev_sal, @prev_sal := salary) salary
  from (
    select `years`.`year`, `months`.`month`, salary
      from `years` cross join `months` 
        left join salary_raise sr
          on sr.month = `months`.`month` 
            and sr.year = `years`.`year`
            and sr.employee_id = 1
      where (`years`.`year` = 2014 or `years`.`year` = 2015)      
      order by `years`.`year` asc, `months`.`month` asc
  ) q cross join (select @salary := null) qq
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83849/21)

Of course you'll need to limit that to not check dates in the future -- that should be pretty easy tho.

Comment: This is tagged 'php' too, so I think it would be better to handle application logic there.

Comment: @strawberry maybe, its still a vaguely useful tool to have in the belt

Comment: Sir you are brilliant! One problem though ... I've tried the query on WAMP and it returns [BLOB] for the known salaries and the rest are NULL. I can do `CAST( if(salary is null, @prev_sal, @prev_sal := salary) AS UNSIGNED ) salary` to get numeric value ... but I can't figure the NULLs. The collation is utf8_unicode_ci and I've put all the fields INT(11).

Comment: .. then your data is weird. can you populate the sqlfiddle link with your example data? what type of field is `salary` ?

Comment: `year`, `month`, `salary` are all INT(11) in all the tables. BTW, `select years.year, months.month, salary` gives an error, it should be: `select years.year, months.month, sr.salary`

Comment: where is this error? there's no error in the demo - works fine. not sure how it wouldnt for you